# Display Multiple Images/Links In CDetailView Yii framework

Tags: php, yii, cdetailview

Help
I have been surfing all day and can not find the topic, how to display multiple images in CDetailView.
My situation are as follows:

1. I have uploaded multiple images, the image jpg files stored in
   /images/doc directory.
2. I have entried path to the images in a cell, means the cell contain
   three filenames with comma separated: abc.jpg, xyz.jpg, abaca.jpg.
3. I wanna to display the link in CDetailView which clickable to open
   the image in new tab browser.

I have tried with this script:

```
array(
                    'name'=>'File Link',
                    'type'=>'raw',
                    'value'=> Links of abc,  
                                       xyz,
```

and also this to display the images

```
$document= CHtml::encode($model->Document);
$file = str_getcsv($document ,",");
```

in CDetailView

```
    array(
            'name'=>'Image',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>link to $file[1]
            ),

 array(
            'name'=>'Image',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>link to $file[2]
            ),

 array(
            'name'=>'Image',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value'=>link to $file[3]
            ),
```

but the result is not as I expected, when I click the link  unrecognized opened by the browser.

I expect result like this: and it should be in Dynamic form may be using 'foreach' statement
how to use it i m not getting it
...
...

```
File Link : abc.jpg
                xyz.jpg
                abaca.jpg <== each must be clickable to the location of the image
```

...
...

Please Help
Regards

sandeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your point, you need to have multiple images per row, right?

have a unanymouse function for value attribute and return the link of images:

```
'value' => function($data){ // here $data represents your model
   $link = '';
   if(!empty($data->images))
       foreach($data->links as $l)
       {
           $link .= CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($file[$i]),Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/' . $file[$i]) . '<br />';
       }
   return $link;
}
```

Comment: ya i needed same thing.......Since we cannot write an function in value or in CDetailView widget but i wrote same function in model and called from value...no error also displaying nothing

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help its simple and best way.......
here is my code document is an has multiple images in database and folder for one attribute

**Function in Model**

```
public function getDocument($model)
{
    $link = '';
    $attribute=CHtml::encode($model->documents);
    $file = str_getcsv($attribute ,",");
    if(!empty($model->documents))
    foreach($file as $i=> $record)
    {
        $link .= CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($file[$i]),Yii::app()->baseURL . '/Documents/' . $file[$i]) . '<br />';
    }
    return $link;
}
```

**In View widget CDetailView**

```
array(
    'name'=>"Uploaded Document ",
    'value'=> $model->getDocument($model),
    'type'=>'raw'   
    ),
```